# Sitecore 8 Arabic search

Tags: lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8

Anyone used the Sitecore 8 Lucene for Arabic language? We are using the default settings and the following code to get search results but we have an issue with Arabic words. It looks like search index contains just English words and doesn't contain Arabic words

```
var indexName = "sitecore_master_index";            
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
var sitecoreService = new SitecoreService(databaseName);
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
  var templates = templateFilter.Split('|');
  var homeId = new ID(Settings.HomeID);

  var results = context.GetQueryable<MySearchItem>(new CultureExecutionContext(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Sitecore.Context.Language.Name)))
                    .Where(item => templates.Contains(item.TemplateName)
                        && item.Content.Contains(fullTextQuery)
                        && item.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name
                        && item.Paths.Contains(homeId)
                        )
                    .Take(SearchResultPerPage)
                    .ToList();
```

Any ideas? What should we change?

Comment: What language code are you using for your arabic site? Just `ar`, `ar-ae` or something else? Have you added an equivilent `analyzer` in the `contentSearch` section of config

Comment: Did you check your index with Luke to see if the Arabic texts are in there?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. We are using ar-ae languge. Also we created the custom index (https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2014/05/30/sitecore-custom-index-with-selected-fields/) and specified fields which we would like to intex to solve the issue. Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

We created the custom index (https://himadritechblog.wordpress.com/2014/05/30/sitecore-custom-index-with-selected-fields/) and specified fields ids which we would like to add to index to solve the issue.